# Calculate the value of column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure.

I want to add the value of column1 with column2 to
like:

```
column3 = (@column1 + @column2)
```

Instead of adding the values my sql stored procedure is concatenating the value.

I declared

```
column1 = 20
column2 = 40
```

The answer must be `column3 = 60` but I am getting `column3 = 2040`.

But in the main table, `column1` and `column2` are declared as `nvarchar` and I cannot change the table. I tried to convert the column in the stored procedure but getting same anser
I converted as `convert(float,@column1)` and `convert(float,@column2)`

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: basicamt nvarchar(50),
ichg nvarchar(50)
set stonichg= round(convert(float,ichg)*0.145,2)        
set bist=(basicamt+ichg+stonichg)  
declare stonichg as float      
declare bist as float

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Also, please always use the *most appropriate* data type - don't store *numbers* or *dates* as strings! If it is a number - use a *numeric* datatype - that's what they're there for, and then your addition will also work as expected!

Comment: the table is created by other person and I am fresher in the company

Comment: @Ibibo what is the type of `column3`? Show DDL and actual code where you are retrieving final output. Are you updating table or just making a select with computed result?

Comment: @IvanStarostin its working fine now i just cast the nvarchar to float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datatype of the columns may be string.

You should try..

```
        column3 = (cast(@column1 as int) + cast(@column2 as int))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Cast` function:

```
select Cast(column_1 as float)+cast(Column_2 as Float) Column_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Define datatypes of parameters properly.

You should do something like this:

```
Declare @column1 INT = 20, @column2 INT = 40, @column3 INT

SET @column3 = @column1 + @column2;

SELECT @column3 AS [Result];
```

Tested on my end. Hope That Helps... :)

Comment: Working I take float

Comment: Then just change the datatype according to your need you will get result. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    column1 nvarchar(50),
    column2 nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(20, 40),
('20','40')

SELECT CAST(column1 as int) + CAST(column2 as int) as column3
FROM @test

SELECT CAST(column1 as float) + CAST(column2 as float) as column3
FROM @test
```

Will give you:

```
column3
60
60
```

Comment: Great! Good for you!